# remove duplication of records in foreach loop in php and cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-1.2

I need help with how to remove the duplication within list of countries based on country_id.

I have a table which includes many projects for a country and counting the projects number which is working fine but need to print without duplication, only one country_id with the count of its project.

The code has been added - if anyone can help it is appreciated

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Country ID</th>
        <th>Country Name</th>
        <th>Number of Place</th>
    </tr>

    <?php 
    $country_counts = [];
    foreach ($projects as $project) {
    $country_id = $project['Project']['country_id'];
    if (isset($country_counts[$country_id])) {
        $country_counts[$country_id]++;
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 30%"><?php echo $project['Project']['country_id']; ?></td>
            <td style="width: 30%"><?php echo 'Country Name'; ?></td>
            <td style="width: 30%"><?php echo $country_counts[$project['Project']['country_id']]; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    } else {
        $country_counts[$country_id] = 1;
    }
    } 
    ?>

</table>
```

the result which i got is
[shows the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOpHk.png)

Comment: A couple of possible solutions - first: modify the SQL query to return unique records or second, assign the ID to an array within the loop and only print the row if this ID does not already exist in the array

Comment: The code suggests that you could likely do the `country_counts` sum within the SQL query rather than within PHP as above

Comment: Thank you could you help me please with an example for the second option assign the id to array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this

```
$checkout_array = array_unique($checkout_array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

I did this for my own you can do it for your array

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to test this code but the idea of what I suggested as the second options goes as follows:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Country ID</th>
        <th>Country Name</th>
        <th>Number of Place</th>
    </tr>

<?php 
    $country_counts=[];
    $ids=array();// Store unique country_id values here
    
    foreach( $projects as $project ) {
        $country_id = $project['Project']['country_id'];

        # Check if the country_id is NOT in the array and display if OK.
        if( isset( $country_counts[ $country_id ] ) && !in_array( $country_id, $ids ) ) {
            $country_counts[$country_id]++;
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 30%"><?php echo $project['Project']['country_id']; ?></td>
        <td style="width: 30%"><?php echo 'Country Name'; ?></td>
        <td style="width: 30%"><?php echo $country_counts[$project['Project']['country_id']]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    
            // add the country_ID to the array so that 
            // on the next iteration of the loop the $ids 
            // array will be checked again and no output if
            // it is already in the array.
            
            $ids[]=$country_id;
        } else {
            $country_counts[$country_id] = 1;
        }
    } 
?>

</table>
```

Comment: I do think much of this could be done directly with the initial SQL query

Comment: Thank you may i ask you for an small example please? because i wasn't able to solve that